# CSV cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '' is not a valid value for 'double'. CSV file error

Tags: xml, file, csv, input, invoice

i am getting an error reading a `csv` file, in this file i store values that has to be of a specific data type for generate an invoice (known as facturae, or electronic bill), so the problem is that i get the error:

```
cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '' is not a valid value for 'double' error
```

This is the `csv` file (i use ; as delimiter in this file, we can call it a database, because contains the values needed for generate 5 invoices) where i get the error:

[image]

Background: I use a xml file as template that contains fields that will be replaced by the values that you see in the csv file,

I see in other threads in stackoverflow similar errors but i didn't found out the problem, i read that the error is due to empty fields, i took care that i don't have empty fields in csv file, in others talk about `"` as text delimiter, i don't understand much about that.

Any help would be aprreciated. Thank you.

PD: I imagine that you will not have problems with the csv file, some fields are in Spanish, it is an example invoice, what matters is the format and the type of the data

One of the xml invoices generated (i use a c++ code for mix the information in the database(`csv` file) with the fields in the template(`xml` file), i think it's not relevant to put it here):

```
    <fe:Facturae xmlns:fe="http://www.facturae.es/Facturae/2009/v3.2/Facturae" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.facturae.es/Facturae/2009/v3.2/Facturae">
  <FileHeader>
    <SchemaVersion>3.2</SchemaVersion>
    <Modality>I</Modality>
    <InvoiceIssuerType>EM</InvoiceIssuerType>
    <Batch>
      <BatchIdentifier>125</BatchIdentifier>
      <InvoicesCount>185</InvoicesCount>
      <TotalInvoicesAmount>
        <TotalAmount>98.27</TotalAmount>
      </TotalInvoicesAmount>
      <TotalOutstandingAmount>
        <TotalAmount>98.27</TotalAmount>
      </TotalOutstandingAmount>
      <TotalExecutableAmount>
        <TotalAmount>98.27</TotalAmount>
      </TotalExecutableAmount>
      <InvoiceCurrencyCode>EUR</InvoiceCurrencyCode>
    </Batch>
  </FileHeader>
  <Parties>
    <SellerParty>
      <TaxIdentification>
        <PersonTypeCode>J</PersonTypeCode>
        <ResidenceTypeCode>R</ResidenceTypeCode>
        <TaxIdentificationNumber>28.22</TaxIdentificationNumber>
      </TaxIdentification>
      <LegalEntity>
        <CorporateName>36.84</CorporateName>
        <RegistrationData/>
        <AddressInSpain>
          <Address>
          29.6
          </Address>
          <PostCode>31565</PostCode>
          <Town>33</Town>
          <Province>35</Province>
          <CountryCode>ESP</CountryCode>
        </AddressInSpain>
        <ContactDetails>
          <Telephone>37</Telephone>
          <ElectronicMail>39</ElectronicMail>
          <ContactPersons>41</ContactPersons>
        </ContactDetails>
      </LegalEntity>
    </SellerParty>
    <BuyerParty>
      <TaxIdentification>
        <PersonTypeCode>J</PersonTypeCode>
        <ResidenceTypeCode>R</ResidenceTypeCode>
        <TaxIdentificationNumber>434</TaxIdentificationNumber>
      </TaxIdentification>
      <AdministrativeCentres>
        <AdministrativeCentre>
            <CentreCode>45</CentreCode>
            <RoleTypeCode>01</RoleTypeCode>
            <Name>47</Name>
            <AddressInSpain>
                <Address>C/ </Address>
                <PostCode>98034</PostCode>
                <Town>Le Havre</Town>
                <Province>Tenerife</Province>
                <CountryCode>ESP</CountryCode>
            </AddressInSpain>
            <CentreDescription>92.5</CentreDescription>
        </AdministrativeCentre>
        <AdministrativeCentre>
            <CentreCode>90.65</CentreCode>
            <RoleTypeCode>02</RoleTypeCode>
            <Name>88</Name>
            <AddressInSpain>
                <Address>C/ </Address>
                <PostCode>84865</PostCode>
                <Town>Dover</Town>
                <Province>Calais</Province>
                <CountryCode>ESP</CountryCode>
            </AddressInSpain>
            <CentreDescription>Alien</CentreDescription>
        </AdministrativeCentre>
        <AdministrativeCentre>
            <CentreCode>568</CentreCode>
            <RoleTypeCode>03</RoleTypeCode>
            <Name>35</Name>
            <AddressInSpain>
                <Address>C/ </Address>
                <PostCode>93107</PostCode>
                <Town>Valencia</Town>
                <Province>Castellon</Province>
                <CountryCode>ESP</CountryCode>
            </AddressInSpain>
            <CentreDescription>96543</CentreDescription>
            </AdministrativeCentre>
        </AdministrativeCentres>
      <LegalEntity>
        <CorporateName>Juan</CorporateName>
        <RegistrationData/>
        <AddressInSpain>
          <Address>
          Suecia
          </Address>
          <PostCode>34885</PostCode>
          <Town>Palermo</Town>
          <Province>Sicilia</Province>
          <CountryCode>ESP</CountryCode>
        </AddressInSpain>
        <ContactDetails>
          <ContactPersons>658476806</ContactPersons>
        </ContactDetails>
      </LegalEntity>
    </BuyerParty>
  </Parties>
  <Invoices>
    <Invoice>
      <InvoiceHeader>
        <InvoiceNumber>1</InvoiceNumber>
        <InvoiceSeriesCode/>
        <InvoiceDocumentType>FC</InvoiceDocumentType>
        <InvoiceClass>OO</InvoiceClass>
      </InvoiceHeader>
      <InvoiceIssueData>
        <IssueDate>2018-04-22</IssueDate>
        <OperationDate>2018-04-21</OperationDate>
        <InvoiceCurrencyCode>EUR</InvoiceCurrencyCode>
        <TaxCurrencyCode>EUR</TaxCurrencyCode>
        <LanguageName>es</LanguageName>
      </InvoiceIssueData>
      <TaxesOutputs>
        <Tax>
          <TaxTypeCode>03</TaxTypeCode>
          <TaxRate>7.00</TaxRate>
          <TaxableBase>
            <TotalAmount>843.25</TotalAmount>
          </TaxableBase>
          <TaxAmount>
            <TotalAmount>158.00</TotalAmount>
          </TaxAmount>
          <EquivalenceSurchargeAmount>
            <TotalAmount>0.00</TotalAmount>
          </EquivalenceSurchargeAmount>
        </Tax>
      </TaxesOutputs>
      <InvoiceTotals>
        <TotalGrossAmount>843.25</TotalGrossAmount>
        <TotalGrossAmountBeforeTaxes>843.25</TotalGrossAmountBeforeTaxes>
        <TotalTaxOutputs>158.00</TotalTaxOutputs>
        <TotalTaxesWithheld>0.00</TotalTaxesWithheld>
        <InvoiceTotal>98.27</InvoiceTotal>
        <TotalOutstandingAmount>98.27</TotalOutstandingAmount>
        <TotalExecutableAmount>98.27</TotalExecutableAmount>
      </InvoiceTotals>
      <Items>
        <InvoiceLine>
          <IssuerTransactionReference/>
          <ItemDescription>  </ItemDescription>
          <Quantity></Quantity>
          <UnitOfMeasure>01</UnitOfMeasure>
          <UnitPriceWithoutTax>843.250000</UnitPriceWithoutTax>
          <TotalCost>843.250000</TotalCost>
          <GrossAmount>843.250000</GrossAmount>
          <TaxesOutputs>
            <Tax>
              <TaxTypeCode>03</TaxTypeCode>
              <TaxRate>7.00</TaxRate>
              <TaxableBase>
                <TotalAmount>843.25</TotalAmount>
              </TaxableBase>
              <TaxAmount>
                <TotalAmount>158.00</TotalAmount>
              </TaxAmount>
              <EquivalenceSurchargeAmount>
                <TotalAmount>0.00</TotalAmount>
              </EquivalenceSurchargeAmount>
            </Tax>
          </TaxesOutputs>
          <AdditionalLineItemInformation/>
        </InvoiceLine>
        <InvoiceLine>
          <IssuerTransactionReference/>
          <ItemDescription>  </ItemDescription>
          <Quantity></Quantity>
          <UnitOfMeasure>01</UnitOfMeasure>
          <UnitPriceWithoutTax>843.250000</UnitPriceWithoutTax>
          <TotalCost>843.250000</TotalCost>
          <GrossAmount>843.250000</GrossAmount>
          <TaxesOutputs>
            <Tax>
              <TaxTypeCode>03</TaxTypeCode>
              <TaxRate>7.00</TaxRate>
              <TaxableBase>
                <TotalAmount>843.25</TotalAmount>
              </TaxableBase>
              <TaxAmount>
                <TotalAmount>158.00</TotalAmount>
              </TaxAmount>
              <EquivalenceSurchargeAmount>
                <TotalAmount>0.00</TotalAmount>
              </EquivalenceSurchargeAmount>
            </Tax>
          </TaxesOutputs>
          <AdditionalLineItemInformation/>
        </InvoiceLine>
      </Items>
      <PaymentDetails>
        <Installment>
          <InstallmentDueDate>2018-04-22</InstallmentDueDate>
          <InstallmentAmount>98.27</InstallmentAmount>
          <PaymentMeans>04</PaymentMeans>
          <AccountToBeCredited>
            <IBAN></IBAN>
          </AccountToBeCredited>
        </Installment>
      </PaymentDetails>
      <AdditionalData>
        <InvoiceAdditionalInformation>Facturae generado por los alumnos </InvoiceAdditionalInformation>
      </AdditionalData>
    </Invoice>
  </Invoices>
</fe:Facturae>
```

Comment: The error relates to an XML file -- presumably the XML file that you generate from the CSV. So we need to see the XML file. The error message will typically show a line/column number helping you to locate the relevant part of the XML file.

Comment: Hello @MichaelKay , I edited the question for add an example of an invoice that generates my program.

Comment: @MichaelKay  A part of the error, 1.2.1, could be line and/or column

Comment: No, 1.2.1 is the clause number in the cvc-datatype-valid constraint in the XSD specification that contains the rule that is being violated.

Comment: Without seeing the schema, and without a line/column number, it's difficult to locate the actual error. It could for example be complaining about the empty `<Quantity>` element.